# How to get Combobox.Datasource to a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, winforms

Following is my code which is binding a `List()` to a `ComboBox` control. I tried to add few items to the CombBox control using `Insert() method` which is `not allowed` as it has been assigned to a datasource. So, how can I get the datasouce back to a new variable (say, var colours2) from cmbColour.DataSource which is returning an object. Thanx !

```
var colours= new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
              {"1x","Green"},
              {"2x","Red"},
              {"3y","Blue"},
              {"4y","Black"}
            }.ToList();

cmbColour.ValueMember = "Key";
cmbColour.DisplayMember = "Value";
cmbColour.DataSource = colours;

var colours2 = //how can I get the DataSource back
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code will return a new dictionary containing the same data you bound to the combo box.

```
var list = (List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>)cmbColor.DataSource;

var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

The property `DataSource` will return the same instance you assigned but because it is typed `Object` you have to cast it back to the actual type before you can access any members.

But why don't you just keep the original dictionary? And it is definitely supported to modify a list bound to a data source - that is the whole point of data binding.

I guess my answer does not really solve your actual problem, only what you think what your problem is. Maybe you can give some additional information about what you are trying to achieve and I or someone else will be able to help you with your underlying problem.

**UPDATE**

This should work for your scenario - I stick with the user example.

```
public class User
{
    public String Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the code for the form.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<User> recentlyAddedUsers = new BindingList<User>();

    private void MainFormLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.comboBoxRecentlyAddedUsers.DataSource = this.recentlyAddedUsers;

        this.comboBoxRecentlyAddedUsers.ValueMember = "Id";
        this.comboBoxRecentlyAddedUsers.DisplayMember = "Name";

        var recentlyAddedUsersFromService = this.GetRecentlyAddedUsers();

        foreach (var user in recentlyAddedUsersFromService)
        {
            this.recentlyAddedUsers.Add(user);
        }
    }

    private void ButtonAddNewUserClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newUser = new User();

        newUser.Id = this.textBoxUserId.Text;
        newUser.Name = this.textBoxUserName.Text;

        this.SaveNewUser(newUser);

        this.recentlyAddedUsers.RemoveAt(0);
        this.recentlyAddedUsers.Insert(newUser);
    }

    private List<User> GetRecentlyAddedUsers()
    {
        // Get a list of recently added users from the database.
    }

    private void SaveNewUser(User user)
    {
        // Save the new user to the database.
    }
}
```

Note the usage of `BindingList<T>` - this will notify the combo box about any changes to the list. A simple `List<T>` would also work but then you have to explicitly tell the combo box to refresh the data binding.

Comment: +1 This works like a charm!!!  Actually, I need keep selected number of items in the list and add one to the top, remove one from bottom of the list. Initial list coming from a web service.

Comment: So you get a list from a service, insert one new element at position 0, remove the last element and bind that updated list to the combo box?

Comment: Yep, that's corrent. I want show user most recent 5 items so that he can select any one to request related data again from a web service (different call).

Comment: Okay, but this can all be done before binding the list to the control. Why do you want to recover the dictionary later? Isn't it enough to get `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood. On Form load I am getting most recently added (say users) from the server using a service. Right? this windows app can add more and more (say users again) into the server all day along. Combobox shows the most recently added usernames. Application user can select any one of them again to retrieve (say user details) from server using selectedValue which is a username.

Comment: I think I got it now - have a look at the example I added, could this work for you? It would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wan't to up vote you more but I can't.. I like using `BindingList<T>` brilliant idea!. Will try and surely let you know. Thanks !

Comment: I have followed your brilliant idea. It is much neater ! something new. Thanks again ! Star !!!

Answer (score 1):

Since `DataSource` is typed as an `object` there's not a clean way to extract the data from it.  If you know the underlying type of the data source (meaning you set it somewhere else so you KNOW what type it is) you can just cast it and add items to the collection.

Be aware that the object will be a REFERENCE not a COPY of the original object, meaning if you set the data source to a dictionary initially then try to extract it to add items you're adding items to the SAME dictionary.

So in your case:

```
 var colours2 = cmbColour.DataSource as List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;
 // can add items to colours2 here (but it is the same instance as colours)
```

Comment: Note that the op calls ToList() on the dictionary before assigning it to the data source, so attempting to cast it to a dictionary returns null.

Answer (score 1):

```
var coloursList = cmbColour.DataSource as List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;
var colours2 = coloursList.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Don't use `as` if you know that the value is always of the type you are casting to. If you expect `x` to be always of type string, use `(String)x` because it will throw an exception if you introduce a bug and `x` happens not to be of type string. With `x as String` the bug will remain unnoticed and it will just look like `x` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data back by using following cast.

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var colours = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"1x", "Green"},
                {"2x", "Red"},
                {"3y", "Blue"},
                {"4y", "Black"}
            }.ToList();

            cmbColour.DataSource = colours;

            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> l1 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            l1 = (List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)cmbColour.DataSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating and new list and assigning it to `l1` just to throw it away with the next statement. Minor detail - the question is about WinForms, not WebForms, but this does not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> c = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("m", "n"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("k", "c")
        };

comboBox1.DataSource = c;

c.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("new","new value"));
```

or

```
var list = (List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>)comboBox1.DataSource;
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("new", "new value"));
```